# navigator.notification.* fails "navigator.notification [undefined] is not an object"

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Any call to a PhoneGap navigator.notification method is failing with the message "**Result of expression navigator.notification [undefined] is not an object**"

I've gone through the full installation and project generation process outlined here: http://phonegap.pbworks.com/Getting-started-with-Android-PhoneGap-in-Eclipse

...and the application works fine when run from Eclipse, except until trying to access the navigator object. Here is the JavaScript code that is throwing the error:

```
var beep = function() {
    try {
        if (navigator != null) {
            navigator.notification.beep(2);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Beep failed: " + e.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that running on the emulator or on your phone? Beep was causing applications to complete crash (the app just closes) when run on phones or the emulator with no notification ringtones present.

Comment: this is in the emulator... I'm just displaying whatever the error message is when trying to access beep(2)... or any other function on the navigator object. I am thinking it might have to do with my dev environment set up, but I'm not finding any information on this particular error message.

Comment: I finally was able to get it to work, though the beep method seems to ignore the parameter (times). The actual error message was caused by an incorrect path to the phonegap.js file.

Comment: Is your problem solved already?

Answer (score 1):

I think the cordova*.js

(src="cordova-2.1.0.js") is not same as in the www folder of your project. I had this same problem & changing the reference in Index.html page solved my problem.

See this link : [phonegap-sample-application-for-android-does-not-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214304/phonegap-sample-application-for-android-does-not-work)