# PhoneGap sample application for android does not work

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to learn Mobile app development using Phonegap for Android platform.  So, I downloaded latest PhoneGap version 1.6. I found a nice article at http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/30862722/phonegap-android-eclipse-quickstart which shows how to set up PhoneGap for Eclipse. After adding sample application in Eclipse i am now able to run the application but, None of the list items seems to be working neither on my emulator nor on my phone. The sample application contains a list(As shown in the link Example) i.e Get Location,Beep,Vibrate,Call 411,Take a Picture,etc. Only call 411 is working what's wrong with the code or phonegap?

logcat

```
04-19 05:45:01.538: I/CordovaLog(325): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
04-19 05:45:01.538: D/DroidGap(325): DroidGap.onCreate()
04-19 05:45:01.559: D/DroidGap(325): DroidGap.loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
04-19 05:45:01.559: D/DroidGap(325): DroidGap: url=file:///android_asset/www/index.html baseUrl=file:///android_asset/www/
04-19 05:45:01.958: D/DroidGap(325): DroidGap.init()
04-19 05:45:02.078: D/PluginManager(325): init()
04-19 05:45:02.178: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(325): Ignore this event
04-19 05:45:02.358: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(325): Ignore this event
04-19 05:45:10.470: D/CordovaLog(325): TypeError: Result of expression 'navigator.notification' [undefined] is not an object.
04-19 05:45:10.470: D/CordovaLog(325): file:///android_asset/www/main.js: Line 21 : TypeError: Result of expression 'navigator.notification' [undefined] is not an object.
04-19 05:45:10.499: E/Web Console(325): TypeError: Result of expression 'navigator.notification' [undefined] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/main.js:21
04-19 05:45:15.108: I/Database(325): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
04-19 05:45:21.128: D/CordovaLog(325): TypeError: Result of expression 'navigator.notification' [undefined] is not an object.
04-19 05:45:21.128: D/CordovaLog(325): file:///android_asset/www/main.js: Line 25 : TypeError: Result of expression 'navigator.notification' [undefined] is not an object.
04-19 05:45:21.128: E/Web Console(325): TypeError: Result of expression 'navigator.notification' [undefined] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/main.js:25
04-19 05:45:22.908: W/KeyCharacterMap(325): No keyboard for id 0
04-19 05:45:22.908: W/KeyCharacterMap(325): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
04-19 05:45:26.228: D/CordovaLog(325): TypeError: Result of expression 'navigator.network' [undefined] is not an object.
04-19 05:45:26.228: D/CordovaLog(325): file:///android_asset/www/main.js: Line 108 : TypeError: Result of expression 'navigator.network' [undefined] is not an object.
04-19 05:45:26.249: E/Web Console(325): TypeError: Result of expression 'navigator.network' [undefined] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/main.js:108
```

Comment: Without logcat or specifics on the errors you are encountering it is not easy to answer your question. Can you provide screen shots or logs showing the problems?

Comment: added logcat which shows 'navigator.notification' error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Likely the name of phonegap*js or cordova*js in your index.html does not match the file name in the assets/www directory.

The AppLaud Eclipse plugin that I created, provides a wizard to configure projects for PhoneGap for Android. See http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/34483744/PhoneGap-Eclipse-PlugIn-for-Android

Answer (score 1):

I think You have spelling mistakes in your code,  or else missed some attributes like charset="utf-8"

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"  charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

it's worked for me but make sure add only first line in your indext.html file not second line. for me after deleting second line only it is worked. add only

add make sure cordova-1.7.0.js exists in www folder.