# Phonegap/Cordova - TypeError: Result of expression 'navigator.network' [undefined] is not an object

Tags: android, cordova

I am using `navigator.network.connection.type` to get the network status of the device. But it shows the error

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'navigator.network' [undefined] is not an object.
```

I tried with Phonegap 1.0.0, Cordova 1.7.0, Cordova 1.7.0rc1, but I still get the same error.

It works fine on iOS but not on Android. Can someone help me with this?

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        checkConnection();
        loaddb();
    }
    function checkConnection() {
        alert(navigator.network);
        if(navigator.network==undefined) {
            window.localStorage.setItem("internetAccessFlag","false");
        } else {
            var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
            var states = {};
            states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
            states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
            states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
            states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

            if(networkState==Connection.UNKNOWN || networkState==Connection.NONE) {
                window.localStorage.setItem("internetAccessFlag","false");
            } else {
                window.localStorage.setItem("internetAccessFlag","true");   
            }
            //alert(window.localStorage.getItem("internetAccessFlag"));
        }
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT:-** I am using Cordova 1.7.0 and plugins.xml has

```
<plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
```

Is there anything I have to do with this?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10216239/1321873

Comment: That does not seem to be the problem. I have the path and name specified correctly.

Comment: Are you waiting for the "deviceready" event before you try to access the navigator.network.connection.type property?

Comment: I added my current code to my question. The alert always shows undefined :(

Comment: That still does not answer @SimonMacDonald 's question. How and when is your `onDeviceReady` function being invoked?

Comment: Updated my code to reflect where I am adding onDeviceReady(). Initially tried calling it on BODY load but the navigator.network was undefined.So, thought the cordova API is not ready by the time BODY loads.So, not calling it anywhere specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is code that works perfectly well for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var deviceInfo = function(){
      alert(navigator.network.connection.type);
    }

    function init(){
        console.log("GOT AN ONLOAD!!!")
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceInfo, true);
    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init();">
      A body...
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, when you moved from iOS to Android did you use the Android version of cordova.js? There is a platform dependent cordova.js for each platform.

Comment: @Simon MacDonald , hii i have given the same code as above but not able to get, i'm using cordova-2.0.0.jar file, please help me

Answer (score 0):

Check your version of phonegap, then download PLUGIN for the current version you're using.
For exemple Cordova 3.X : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html