# phonegap navigator.notification.alert doesn't work

Tags: cordova, notifications

The title is self explanatory, I ca't figure out why tho.

sources:
www/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);

        navigator.notification.alert('PhoneGap Alert', null, 'Title', 'Button');
    }
};
```

config.xml in android/res/xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.helloCordova" version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
    <name>Hello Cordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification" />
    </feature>
    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" />
    <preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="8" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
</widget>
```

and androidmanifest.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0.0" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.acs.acs_mobile" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="main" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
</manifest>
```

I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't work with no luck for the past hours.
I'm realtivley new to phonegap so please If I'm missing something let me know...

PS. Phonegap -version : 3.0.0-0.14.3 , device sdk 8 , AVD sdk 8 (both same result)

**Update** after wrapping the code inside a try catch I got this error message:

```
result of expression 'navigator.notification' undefined is not an object
```

AS mentioned in [PhoneGap sample application for android does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214304/phonegap-sample-application-for-android-does-not-work) and 
[navigator.notification.* fails "navigator.notification [undefined] is not an object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006409/navigator-notification-fails-navigator-notification-undefined-is-not-an-obj)

The cause is : `Likely the name of phonegap*js or cordova*js in your index.html does not match the file name in the assets/www directory.` but I only have phonegap.js and cordova.js in platforms/android/assets/www and I'm including with the exact same name... Still can't figure this out...

**UPDATE**

If I do a remote build the app is working ok with local build it doesn;t altho I have installed the plugins as mentioned for version 3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I built your project using Cordova CLI 3.0.9, using the command line tools and following the docs listed here (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification). I used your HTML and JS code and the dialog popped up just fine.

When looking through the other files, I noticed a difference in `config.xml`; my `config.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.helloCordova" version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
    <name>Hello Cordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Vibration">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.vibration.Vibration" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
    </feature>
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
</widget>
```

Notice that mine has **org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification** - yours is missing the `dialogs` namespace for some reason. Is this on purpose? If you add "dialogs" namespace, does it work?  What about if you rebuild using the latest CLI version?

Comment: hmm correct but if I'm not mistaken I had those pasted in there and tried to run it with no luck. Let me test again and I'll let you know.

Comment: Did you upgrade Cordova CLI? If so, is it adding `value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />` to config.xml?

Comment: Everything works now. It seems it was a broken cordova installation. I removed it completely and reinstalled and I'm having 0 issues now. Apparently that's why config.xml wasn't as it should be.

Answer (score 2):

All that you have to do is add this feature to your project...
Stand up con the phonegap project folder (not the platform folder), for example: cd MobileAplications/MyPhoneGapExample
then, add the plugin (I installed cordova instead off phonegap, so I suposed if you install phonegap you have to use the "phonegap" command): cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs

I hope it works for you!!

PD:
If someone dont know whats the difference between the platform folder and the project folder, here is the document that can show the difference: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Answer (score 2):

I am using visual studio 2015, and I solved this problem by adding the Notification plugin.

Double click your config.xml in your poject, and select Notification plugin and install.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to add this feature to your config.xml file

```
 <feature name="Notification">
  <param name="wp-package" value="Notification"/>
</feature>
```

...and a good advice to copy the config.xml file to your www directory.

Answer (score 0):

You will only see working from the android emulator or a device, in ripple does not work.

```
    var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {        
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },

    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
    // 'pause', 'resume', etc.
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        //this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
            console.log(navigator.notification);

            navigator.notification.alert(
                    'You are the winner!',  // message
                    alertDismissed,         // callback
                    'Game Over',            // title
                    'Done'                  // buttonName
                );
            //navigator.notification.beep(2);
    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};app.initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinstal APK App on device. It is only when the system is installed that the system consents to the permissions. Only rebuild does not work. After reinstall the permissions are displayed on the screen and active.