# Click button event using jQuery/JavaScript in PhoneGap 2.9 does nothing

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, buttonclick

I am developing a mobile application for android, using Phonegap 2.9 and Eclipse Juno.  I saw many posts related to button click events using Javascript and JQuery and nothing seems to be working. I mean, when I click the button, no alert appears! I've tried also both `<a href=...` and `<input ...` and `<button type="submit" ...` and neither of them works for the same `.js`.

---

My head part in `.html` file is this:

```
 <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">

    <title>Sign-Up</title>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patrick+Hand|Permanent+Marker|Exo|Nunito|Limelight|Ubuntu|Montserrat|Audiowide|Architects+Daughter' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- import stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/sign-up.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/sign-up-eng-fonts.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../jQuery-Mobile-Bootstrap-Theme-master/themes/Bootstrap.css">

    <!-- import js --> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../jss/connect.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../jss/sign-up.js"></script>

 </head>
```

---

My current part of code in `.html` file that creates the button is this :

```
                <div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-a"><button type="submit" id="cancel" data-theme="d">Cancel</button></div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b">
                            <input type="button" value="Register" id="submitt" data-theme="a" /></div>
                            <!--<a href="#" data-inline="button" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Register</a>-->
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
```

---

The `connect.js` contains this code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // checkConnection();

        document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
        document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
    }

function onOffline() {
    navigator.notification.alert('Please enable your Wi-fi and re-open the application!', close_app, 'Wi-fi', 'Okay');
}

function close_app() {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}

function onOnline() {
    }
```

---

and my `sign-up.js` contains this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

 function onDeviceReady() {

        document.getElementById('submitt').addEventListener('click', checkk, false);

            function checkk(){
                 navigator.notification.alert("I am here.", null, 'Here', 'Okay');
            }

    }
```

---

PROBLEM:
When I run the application and press the button, the page stays as it is. It doesn't even refresh or display the alert I wrote.

---

When I try the other solution with the `onclick="register()` in `sign-up.html` file and have the function `register()` in my `sign-up.js` file, the Eclipse's LogCat it says : `file:///android_asset/www/htmls/home.html: Line 1 : Uncaught ReferenceError: register is not defined`. The `home.html` is the first page of the application. But the register button is in the `sign-up.html` -only here I call in header the `sign-up.js` (contains the `register()`.)-

Comment: I thought I would die during editing your code... About question: take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827959/phonegap-navigator-notification-alert-doesnt-work).

Comment: I am sorry about the editing. It is just I didn't have time to fix it by myself and the internet connection was awful. I will check it right now, even though as I saw it isn't about `click event` on button. I will see the logic in JavaScript. thank you

Comment: Oops I too have edit your code for formatting. It was a pain :(. Please check whether  the code has been formatted correctly. You need to use a good EDITOR.. WebStorm, sublime text, Notepad++, etc. are good editors for HTML and JS.

Comment: I use Sublime Text. I will never post something before edit completely the format. thank you and I'm sorry.

Comment: @marialena and what about question - does mentioned link help?

Comment: I added some missing lines in my `config.xml` file eand now i see the `index.js` to understand how exactly this works.

Comment: @Regent the link in the user doesn't work so i found [this](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification) . It was very helpful with different types of notifications. Now, I have to understand the Javascript file written in question and the way you "call it" in html ans try it.

Comment: Well, yes, docs is the real place to look into. All I wanted to say is that you probably didn't include Notifications plugin.

Comment: Yes I added the Plugin but I am very confused with what code to write in `Javascript file` and in the `Html file`. I mean how to trigger that the button is been clicked? I tried the javascript file in the link that you sent to me but no message appears in my screen. I tried the `onclick()` event and again nothing appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *finally* managed to solve my problem. 
It has nothing to do with the button. The problem was about the JavaScripts.

---

- First of all, I changed the order of the JavaScripts calling in `home.html` and `sign-up.html`.
  (1. JQuerys from the web, 2. cordova.js, 3. connect.js, 4. all the other javaScripts)

  `home.html`:

  ```
  <title>Guide-Me For-All</title>

  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patrick+Hand|Permanent+Marker|Exo|Nunito|Limelight|Ubuntu|Montserrat|Audiowide|Architects+Daughter' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- import stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/home.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/home-eng-fonts.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../jQuery-Mobile-Bootstrap-Theme-master/themes/Bootstrap.css">

  <!-- import js --> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../cordova.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../jss/connect.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../jss/change_page.js"></script>

  <script src="../plugins/page-swipe-iscroll/iscroll.js"></script>
  <script src="../plugins/page-swipe-iscroll/scroll.js"></script>
  ```

---

---

- In the `home.html` I changed the way I was navigating to another page to this:

  ```
                          <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="f" data-icon="heart" onclick="change_page();">Sign-Up Now!</a>
  ```

This is required because as i read in the Google, it is better to change a page from JavaScript instead of the `<a href="....."`.

---

- So, I created the `change_page.js`. It's content is the above:

`document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);`

```
// PhoneGap is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Empty
}

// alert dialog dismissed
function alertDismissed() {
    // do something
}

// Show a custom alert
//
function change_page() {
    document.location.href = '../htmls/sign-up.html';
}
```

---

- In my `sign-up` page I changed the the button to this:

  ```
                              <a href="#" onclick="register();" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Register</a>
  ```

---

- In my `sign-up.js` file I wrote that code:

  `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);`

  ```
  // PhoneGap is ready
  //
  function onDeviceReady() {
      // Empty
  }

  // alert dialog dismissed
  function alertDismissed() {
      // do something
  }

  // Show a custom alert
  //
  function register() {
      navigator.notification.alert(
          'hello!',  // message
          alertDismissed,         // callback
          'Game Over',            // title
          'Done'                  // buttonName
      );
  }
  ```

---

So, the main problem was the way of navigate to the next page, because the JavaScript was working only in the first `.html` page. Hope it helps anyone who has the same problem!