# Cannot read property "alert" of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm new in jQuery

That's my js code, can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    app.initialize();
});
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bind();
    },         
    bind: function() {            
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.deviceready, false);
        $(".buttonConferma").on("tap", selezione.conferma);
    },         
    deviceready: function() {
        app.start();
    },     
    start: function() {                        
        }
    };             
var selezione = {
         conferma: function() {              
               navigator.notification.alert("Confermato");
            }
        }
```

The error come when I click the `.buttonConferma`, which is:

```
<div data-role="content" class="buttonConfermaContainer">
                <a data-role="button" class="button buttonConferma"
                     data-icon="check" data-iconpos="right">CONFERMA</a>
            </div>
```

Shouldn't this be just like an alert? 
 `navigator.notification.alert("Confermato");`

I get this error:

> **Uncaught TypeError:** Cannot read property 'alert' of undefined

That's my HTML anchor

```
<div data-role="content" class="buttonConfermaContainer">
                <a data-role="button" class="button buttonConferma"
                     data-icon="check" data-iconpos="right">CONFERMA</a>
            </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey @Mattew Trincanati, could you edit your post and provide the error you get?

Comment: navigator is a browser object. don't you mean `alert`?

Comment: Does this work? `alert("Confermato");`

Comment: navigator is because I'm trying to develop this using phonegap, I thought that was kind of a mobile alert, now I'll try with simple alert

Comment: Could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827959/phonegap-navigator-notification-alert-doesnt-work  and http://stackoverflow.com/a/18927028/1414562

Comment: well yes, the simple alert work, but why navigator.notification.alert("Confermato"); doesn't work? phonegap example seems to use that instead of an alert

Comment: Did you add the javascript phonegap reference(s) to the page header so the `navigator.notification.alert` is accessible? Looks it is not initialized.

Comment: is navigator an object? try `if(navigator==='undefined'){alert('navigator not defined')}`

Comment: The references seems ok because if I change on alert("confirmed"); everything work

Comment: 'navigator not defined' does not show, so it seems to be defined

Comment: Fucntion `alert()` works in every browser (it's build in) and you do not need any references. However `navigator.notification.alert` is another implementation of alert function (more suitable for phones).

Comment: I will go for a simple alert..

Answer (score 1):

Just add Notification Plugin in your app

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert

and make sure you will fire alert function after deviceready event of phonegap/cordova.